# SWITCH TRUE WITH OR in power bi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, kpi

I have 15 columns in a power bi table. I would like to create new measure that will return the column names if the percentage value of any columns is less than 60%.

Example table:

| ID | total | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a100 | 50 | 35 | 10 | 5 | 6 |
| a101 | 36 | 25 | 5 | 12 | 18 |

I created a new measure for each column that shows the percentage

```
%col2 = SUM(col2)/SUM(total)*100
%col3 = SUM(col3)/SUM(total)*100
%col4 = SUM(col4)/SUM(total)*100
%col5 = SUM(col5)/SUM(total)*100
```

By the new measure above, I will get col2 >60%

What I would like is to create a visual, maybe by kpi or a table that will return only the columns that have less than 60%.

I tried the following:

```
col_to_improv = SWITCH(TRUE(), OR(table[col2] < 60, "columnname", table[col3] < 60, "col_name2", table[col4] < 60, "col_name3"), table[col5] < 60, "col_name4],"")
```

I would like to show only the column names that has less than 60%, otherwise, do not show.

From the above example table, In the kpi (or other visual), I am expecting only col3,col4, and col5, because they have less than 60%.

Comment: I'm thinking about using of COLUMNSSTATISTICS(); ADDCOLUMNS() and CONCATENAX() and SWITCH() of course

Comment: Please, provide some desired result example.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to transpose your table (if it's able) because it's easier to work with values than column names.

[image]
Don't forget to add to your table one row with metrics description (Column1 in my example)

If you do so you with get desired result with pretty easy DAX measure:

```
col_to_improv =
SWITCH(
    TRUE,
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Column2]) < 60,
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Column1])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies, I should have made it clearer. In the table were rows of values, and the avg row as shown in the example is not really there but as a result of a 'new measure'

Answer (score 1):

Column names - [Table Name],[Column Name] comes from COLUMNSTATISTICS(), so, don't change them, the rest you can name according to your model

```
VAR myTableStat=
        Filter(
            COLUMNSTATISTICS()
            ,[Table Name]="MyTable"
        )
        
VAR withSUM=
       ADDCOLUMNS(
            myTableStat
            ,"colSum",
                      SWITCH(
                               [Column Name]
                               ,"col2",SUM(MyTable[col2])
                               ,"col3",SUM(MyTable[col3])
                               ,"col4",SUM(MyTable[col4])
                               ,"col5",SUM(MyTable[col5])
                       )

                         
        )
VAR totalSum= SUM(MyTable[total])
VAR  withAveLessThen60 =
        FILTER(
            withSUM
            ,AND(
                DIVIDE(
                        [colSum]
                        ,totalSum
                )<0.6
                ,NOT ISBLANK([colSum])
            )
        )
            
VAR result = 
    CONCATENATEX(
                withAveLessThen60
                ,IF(
                    NOT ISBLANK([colSum])
                    ,[Column Name]                  
                )
                ,"; "
                
    )
        
RETURN 
      result
```

[image]

Comment: HI, Thanks. However, I cannot seem to make this work for the average value that is a measure and not actual rows from the table. I thought I am able to find a way to include that but the COLUMNSTATISTICS(), [Table Name], and [Column NAme] are throwing errors.  For the ColumnsTatistics(): `PArameter is not the correct type` both [Table Name] and [column name] throw `Cannot find [Table Name]` and `cannot find [Column Name]`

Comment: I tested the measure before I post and i got a result. Can you post your final code? Regarding measure instead of row. I’ll correct it on Monday. But if you put a code of measure instead of measure It may work.

Comment: But you get an error, so there is other problem as well.

Comment: What do you receive with  ~CountRows(COLUMNSTATISTICS()) ~

Comment: I replaced your line `"col1",AVERAGE(yourTableName[col1])` with `"ID",SUM(tablename[col2])/SUM(tablename[total])*100`. IT did not throw an error but the columnstatistics() and the column Name that you provided

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the point. Can you, please, explan once more? More details about what's happend.

Comment: If you'll add the full code of the measure I'd be able to define if the problem is in syntax. It can happens that due to a contex the  tablename[col2] has zero rows qty and this can case an error as well. In general, the best way to get the result is check values step by step with a DAX studio, or by checking indirect values like CountRows()

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question above and included the measure code

Comment: Hi @buddingpro. I altered the measure. In a DAX studio it works

Comment: You can mark it as answer if it's ok.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies, I am still playing around with it, and I am also checking in DAX studio. I am still getting the same error I mentioned before.

Comment: I was able to make the measure work, but `couldn't load the data for this visual` further it says: `tablename[measure]:COLUMNSTATISTICS() cannot be used with a filter context.`

Comment: @buddingpro. thank you for your feedback. I added a screenshot from my PBI. It means that the measure itself is correct, at least for the sample you gave. The problem comes from something else. I can't define how exactly comes the error. You can attach a dummy pbix file with you visual and data and your measure that gives the error. At least post your measure, so I can try to find the problem out.